# Doubt in a step of the proof of Rado-Kneser-Choquet theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

I am trying to prove Rado-Kneser-Choquet theorem, which states that if $f$ is sense preserving self homeomorphism of the unit circle $\partial D$. Then harmonic extension $F$ of $f$ is self homeomorphism of the unit disk D. I have some doubt in a step in between.

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be unit disk and $f:\partial D\to \partial D$ be sense preserving self homeomorphism of $\partial D$. Let $F$ be harmonic extension of $f$. In the proof it uses a statement: $F$ is locally injective (this is easily provable) and since $f$ is sense preserving, then $F$ is sense preserving throughout $D$.

Can anyone help me out with this. I am not able to prove this.

Comment: Could you please tell me the reference from where you are reading the proof?